# Funcion OLD en input SELECT

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, blade

estoy trabajando con la actualizacion / creacion de registros en el cual dentro de un formulario tengo un input de tipo select.
Estoy queriendo utilizar la funcion OLD que en el caso de que si se genera un error de validacion a la hora de hacer el submit el formulario se autocomplete con los resultados anteriormente escritos.

En todos mis otros campos esta funcion anda correctamente, unicamente nose como implementarla en los de tipo select.

```
<select name="branch_id" class="form-control">
    @forelse ($branches as $branch)
    <option value="{{$branch->id}}" {{$branch->id===$employee->branch_id ? 'selected' : ''}}>
    {{$branch->name}}
    </option>
    @empty
    <option>No hay puestos registrados</option>
    @endforelse
</select>
```

Lo que hace esta funcion es recorrer el array de branches (sucursales) y si el id es igual al de $employee->id lo selecciona como predeterminado, hasta ahi todo bien.
El problema lo tengo cuando el formulario tiene algun tipo de error de validacion me devuelve el formulario pero este campo no sigue en el anteriormente seleccionado.

Ya probe hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
<option value="{{$branch->id}}" {{old('branch_id',$branch->id)===$employee->branch_id ? 'selected' : ''}}>
{{$branch->name}}
</option>
```

Y no funciono. Alguien me podria dar una mano?

Comment: No, eso es lo que explico que probe y no funciono

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución: Estaba fallando por la comparación estricta `===` dado que el valor retornado por `old` es un string y el `id` es un entero.

```
<option value="{{$branch->id}}" {{old('branch_id' , $employee->branch_id)==$branch->id ? 'selected' : ''}}>
        {{$branch->name}}
</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenía la misma duda con el tema del old() en los elementos , pero en mi caso tuve que compararlo con el mismo id que estaba pasando en el foreach

Exactamente en la linea

```
<option value="{{ $id }}" {{ old('category_id')==$id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ trans($category) }}</option>
```

EL código completo aquí:

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('category_id_id') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
    <label>{{ trans('cruds.ticket.fields.category') }}*</label>
    <select name="category_id" class="form-control select2" >
        @foreach($categories as $id => $category)
            <option value="{{ $id }}" {{ old('category_id')==$id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ trans($category) }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    @if($errors->has('category_id_id'))
        <em class="invalid-feedback"> {{ $errors->first('category_id_id') }} </em>
    @endif
</div>
```

Espero le sirva a alguien si tampoco quería compararlo con el id de otra variable